# Making a surface fullscreen in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have a display surface

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

which I then want to make fullscreen which I do by

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Which causes the screen to go to fullscreen. However, the surface does not take up the full computer screen, having black spaces on either side, and the mouse will only move within the surface area. How can I get the surface to take up the full area of my computer screen? I'm using python 3.3 with pygame 1.9.2a0.

Comment: I have the very same issue, but when I'm using Python 2.7.3 with PyGame (version unsure) on a Win7 system. The same program perfectly works, also in FULLSCREEN on any other machine, just not with Win7. It would therefore be interesting to know, what system you are using.

Comment: I'm also on Win7. I'm thinking the problem may be with the (0, 0) size not getting the full resolution, though I'm not sure why. It does go to the full size if I set the original display surface as (0, 0) but if I fullscreen the surface it doesn't.

Comment: That's interesting. Well, I will have a closer look into it, I need to get it to fullscreen under any system :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see the problem.

Yes, pygame will make the game fullscreen, but the dimensions you chose limits game interaction area, and making those black thingies.

I suggest making the dimensions a bit bigger.

Comment: Not quite, the problem is that the display surface doesn't take up the full area of the computer screen. I'll reword my question now.

Comment: Yeah, it should. I'll get the screen resolution with os or some other library, so that the surface matches up with the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN
```

This is the only line of script you need to use for what you want. Using the following line of script you add parameters to the fullscreen code above and limits how far the game can expand.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

So by deleting that your game should expand to the full size of your screen without a problem. This is an example of the code I am using.

```
# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 1350
screen_height =620
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

If I were to put the re-sizable code in conjunction with what I have now, it will use the screen_width and screen_height for how big the game is full-screen. I tested this to make sure.
Hope I was able to help you.